# Warning after ArangoDB upgrade to 3.4: collection '_apps' does not have all persistent LocalDocumentIds

Tags: arangodb

I just upgraded my docker image of ArangoDB from 3.3.19 to 3.4 as follows

docker-compose down,

pull latest docker image,

docker-compose run --rm arangoService arangod --database.auto-upgrade,

docker-compose up

It all looks good afterwards. The DB and Foxx services work, but I noticed the following warning while the database.auto-upgrade was running:

```
WARNING {engines} collection '_apps' does not have all persistent LocalDocumentIds; 
cannot be linked to an arangosearch view
```

Is this something I need to do something about, specially since I want to start playing with arangosearch?

In unrelated things, I noticed that rocks DB is now the default engine. Is it recommended to move my existing MMFiles to RocksDB in terms of future proofing or should I leave it in MMFiles until memory becomes an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is nothing to worry about. It has already been removed by this [commit](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/7611), which is included in the next docker image.

Regarding the storage engine - RocksDB is optimized for data-sets that are bigger than main memory, it depends on your data.

For more details please have a look at the following links:

https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/rocksdb-storage-engine/
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/architecture/storage-engine/

Comment: I just reproduced getting these warnings with the official 3.4.0 release. However, they will only appear if the 3.3 server was not shut down gracefully.

Comment: I agree with @Maximilian Kernbach about these messages being harmless. However, the latest official 3.4.0 release may still produce these warnings when upgrading after an ungraceful shutdown of an MMFiles database. It is now addressed via this [pull request](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/7812).

Comment: I am now getting this same error (in some environments, not all) when upgrading from Arango 3.3 to 3.6. Arango has been trying to start for over an hour and is still not up. This messages is repeated in the logs. Since 3.6 already has the referenced commit, and I'm still seeing this message, should I be worried?

Comment: Update: My Arango eventually finished the upgrade and came up. I saw the message `2020-03-03T16:29:54Z [1] INFO [0de5e] database upgrade passed`